# asp:Button isn't processed by server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

On my page I am trying to put up a button inside an asp:ListView

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="button_Click" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
```

My bound collection has 2 items so listview should generate a table with two rows

```
<table>
    <tr><td>//button goes here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>//button goes here</td></tr>
</table>
```

However when I check the source of the page that was sent from the server, it looks like it cuts off right as it's about to generate the button (in fact the rest of the entire page doesn't get generated):

```
 <table>
    <tr><td>
```

I'm running this out of Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0 - is it possible that the built-in server is unable to recognize the tag? Has anyone else experienced something like this? I don't have a proper IIS set up yet so I can't check how it'd be rendered there.

Comment: Is there any kind of error that you are getting ?

Comment: @Apurv Not a single one. Tried FireBug - no errors show up.

Comment: @Apurv I have upvoted your comment as thanks for taking a look at my question despite it being rather silly. I hope it's not against the community rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So being very new to ASP.NET, I have forgotten to place my page between the `<form runat="server"></form>` tags. I've now added those in and button gets rendered.

The odd part now is that the `<asp:Repeater>` and `<asp:ListView>` did work but the only explanation I can think of is that these controls probably have the `<form>` tag embedded...

Feel free to close question or delete it altogether (it's a little embarrassing now, actually!).

Comment: form tag is important when receiving data on the server. So without form tag, you can get the data from server to client, but not from client to server.